# How can I Continue to use Debian Testing after Bookworm becomes the stable distribution?

Tags: debian, package-management

I am currently using Debian testing (bookworm).

Based on current experience, my confidence in the stability of testing is firm. I would like to use the next Debian testing when Bookworm becomes the current stable distribution.

Will this happen automatically if I continue to use testing or will it require some intervention on my part.

Answer (score 1):

**Short** version:  Edit /etc/apt/sources.list file. Replace `bookworm` with `testing` **or even better with next testing version
name**.

I personally prefer to avoid "unexpected" changes in testing versions.
It is much better to intentionally choose exact switch moment.

For longer version see [`man sources.list`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sources.list)

Comment: “Even better with next testing version name” — I don’t think this is better. For one thing, it won’t work currently (`trixie` doesn’t exist in the repositories); for another, it doesn’t produce the desired outcome definitively, it only pushes the issue back by two years or so.

Comment: AFAIR I had used "testing" i sources.list but last time it created some "security warnings" by apt (and required some extra pushing(.

Comment: Try following your own advice: use `trixie` in `sources.list`, and see what happens with `apt update`.